# VBScript to check files in folder and email the file name not updated past 1 hour

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, vba, vbscript, vb6

I need help, I'm new to VBScript.
I need a vbscript which can check a folder which contain 10 to 20 .csv files, need to check the date & time and send report of which files have not been updated for more then past 15 minutes to 1 hour.

Files are located on a network share. ( \Users\files )

Thanks for the reply n guide.

I did change the code as for my needs, still need few more help.

```
   DirCheck="W:\RC"

   set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set FOL = fso.GetFolder(DirCheck)

    Set output = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\output.txt",True) 

    For each fil in FOL.files
        strExtension=Fso.GetExtensionName(fil.name)
        If UCase(strExtension)="CSV" Then
        output.WriteLine fil.name

     End If
    Next

    Set fso=Nothing
```

i want its write the file name + last modify date of the file in the output.txt. currently its writing the file name. can any one guide me?

Comment: -1 because post shows zero research effort. Start here perhaps: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_filesystem.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileSystemObject is your friend here, learn to love FSO if you are working with files in VBScript.

This example should help - shows time in minutes since last modification for CSV files - will work on a share as long as the user running the script has read permissions on the share.

```
DirCheck="C:\test"

set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set FOL = fso.GetFolder(DirCheck)

For each fil in FOL.files
    strExtension=Fso.GetExtensionName(fil.name)
    If UCase(strExtension)="CSV" Then
        strFileName=fil.name
        wscript.echo("File : " & strFileName)
        Wscript.echo("Mins since last modificaion: " & DateDiff("n",fil.DateLastModified,now))
    End If
Next

Set fso=Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply n guide.
I did change the code as for my needs, still need few more help.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the docs. If you have exchange you have to set different properties.

```
Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
emailObj.From     = "ndy@gail.com"

emailObj.To       = "ndy@gail.com"

emailObj.Subject  = "Test CDO"
emailObj.TextBody = "Test CDO"

emailObj.AddAttachment "c:\windows\win.ini"

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration

emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = "ndy"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = "password"
emailConfig.Fields.Update

emailObj.Send

If err.number = 0 then Msgbox "Done"
```